Fine tune llama3 with message replies like dataset (slack)
I want to fine tune llama3 on a dataset in which the data structure is a list of messages considering the below rules:

there are channels.
in each channel there are messages from all sort of users.
each message might have replies the corresponds to its context.

I already have the logic to scrap all data, but I'm a bit confused regarding how the dataset structure should look like.
I've read llama3 documentation and it looks like the below template should be applied (example taken from: https://llama.meta.com/docs/model-cards-and-prompt-formats/meta-llama-3/):
<|begin_of_text|><|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>

You are a helpful AI assistant for travel tips and recommendations<|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>

What can you help me with?<|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>

Assuming each individual message/replay looks like that:
<timestamp> - <user>: <message>

How should the end result of the data should look like?
Is it a list of dict? If so, how are the replies should be placed in it?
I dared to ask GPT4o and it gave me the below example:
prompt_example_1 = [
    {"role": "system", "message": "Channel: general"},
    {"role": "user", "message": "U12345678 [2023-06-01 12:00:00]: Main message in the channel"},
    {"role": "assistant", "message": "U87654321 [2023-06-01 12:05:00]: Reply to the main message"},
    {"role": "assistant", "message": "U23456789 [2023-06-01 12:10:00]: Another reply to the main message"},
    {"role": "user", "message": "U23456789 [2023-06-01 12:15:00]: Another main message"},
    {"role": "assistant", "message": "U34567890 [2023-06-01 12:20:00]: Reply to the second main message"}
]

It doesn't feel right to me.
What will happen if I'll shuffle the dataset? All the replies will lose their association with their parent message.
I came across this documentation from huggingface: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/chat_templating
It made me think I can actually use apply_chat_template as follows:
dataset = [
    [
        {"role": "system", "content": "Channel: general"},
        {"role": "user", "content": "U12345678 [2023-06-01 12:00:00]: Main message in the channel"},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "U87654321 [2023-06-01 12:05:00]: Reply to the main message"},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "U23456789 [2023-06-01 12:10:00]: Another reply to the main message"}
    ],
    [
        {"role": "system", "content": "Channel: random"},
        {"role": "user", "content": "U23456789 [2023-06-01 12:15:00]: Another main message"},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "U34567890 [2023-06-01 12:20:00]: Reply to the second main message"}
    ]
]

hf_dataset = Dataset.from_dict({"chat": dataset})

hf_dataset = hf_dataset.map(lambda x: {
    "formatted_chat": tokenizer.apply_chat_template(
        x["chat"], 
        tokenize=False, 
        add_generation_prompt=False
    )
})

